# How can I fix this Excel VBA code to ingore empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I use this to alphabetize my Excel worksheets by a cell. Can someone help me fix this code to ignore empty cells or sort them to the end?

Here is the code i am using to do this but i don't know how to add a string to ingore the empty cells or put them at the end.

```
Sub SortWksByCell()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        For j = i To Worksheets.Count
            If UCase(Worksheets(j).Range("A260")) < _
              UCase(Worksheets(i).Range("A260")) Then
                Worksheets(j).Move before:=Worksheets(i)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

it puts all the worksheet with empty `A260` range at the first of the sort i want it at the last

Answer (score 4):

Add an `Else If` to test to see if the range is an empty string. If so, move it to the end. Also you need to use a reverse loop else you will miss worksheets.

```
Sub SortWksByCell()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        For j = Sheets.Count To i Step -1
            If UCase(Sheets(j).Range("A260")) < UCase(Sheets(i).Range("A260")) Then
                Sheets(j).Move before:=Sheets(i)
            ElseIf Sheets(j).Range("A260") = "" Then
                Sheets(j).Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, you will need a reverse loop? `For i = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1: For j = Sheets.Count To i Step -1`

Comment: Plz do - or post your own and i'll delete mine lo;

Comment: you can also ignore empty cells by using the `Range.SpecialCells` method